# Use multiple ports in Docker multistage build

Tags: docker, selenium, nginx, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am using MultiStage in docker for performing tests tasks.
The base image is Selenium which exposes port 4444 and the staged image is nginx for other operations.

The nginx has port 80 exposed.
If I have to expose both ports, only the port80 is exposed, and not 4444 when using

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 4444:4444 someimage:2
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox AS base
RUN python3 try.py

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=base /report.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how the multistage build works.

Your final image **DOES NOT** contain everything from every image you specified in your *Dockerfile*.

It **DOES** contain everything from the image specified in the last `FROM` instruction and results of all the commands below.

In you case it contains everything from image *nginx:latest* and file *report.html* copied from previous build stage - which means that when you use it to run a container there is nothing listening on port 4444, so exposing it is meaningless.

Comment: Are there any other way to achieve that? As a workaround, I have installed nginx and have setup multiple ports

Comment: You can create a custom image that contains both Selenium and nginx. Other than that - no, there's no way to combine multiple Docker images.